# How does tab-press work in HTML page

Tags: html

I got some problem when user pressed the TAB-key. There should be a static way in which the user can jump from one form element to the next.

I know there is a posibility to declare in which order the elements should be selected with TabIndex.

Now I would like to know how does the browser decide which element is focused as next Element after pressing Tab.

EDIT: Does it only walk down the dom or does look it on the position on rendered Website, that's what i want to know.

Comment: Source code position?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear... If you already know about the `TabIndex`, then isn't it obvious that the browser cycles through all elements in the order of that setting where given, and the order of creation of elements where _not_ given? Note that "the order of creation" is _not_ necessarily the order of appearance in the DOM tree. Content may have been created in a dynamic manner.

Comment: In general, it should be the order of your html code.

Comment: @arkascha I beg your pardon? I was suggesting that the default tabindex is probably the order in which elements appear in the source code. I don't think browsers build complex rules based upon CSS layouts-- but I may be wrong, thus why I left a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @arkascha look at answer below seems my questiona wasn't as unclear as you thought

Answer (score 1):

The process of deciding in which order to skip from one focusable element to the next is fairly complex. The first step is to find out, which elements may gain a tab focus.

There is an article by Maks Nemisj that covers your question in length: [“Focus, tabIndex and behavior of browsers”](https://nemisj.com/focusable/).